# GetValueInvocationException reading a cell from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

This is a very strange error I have. I was reading fields from an Excel spreadsheet and everything went fine. Then I added another column to read and it did not work again.

```bsh
$columnIn = 8
$columnHa = 7
$ExcelSheet.Cells.Item($row,$columnIn).text
$ExcelSheet.Cells.Item($row,$columnHa).text
# These are working quite fine, but when I add
$columnRe = 5
$ExcelSheet.Cells.Item($row, $columnRe).text
# This is the annoying error: GetValueInvocationException
```

This is already strange, then I put instead of `$columnRe` the value 5 in the call `Item($row,5).text` and it worked!
After that I changed the assignment into a cast:

```bsh
[int] $ColumnInsight = 6
[int] $ColumnHashtag = 7
[int] $ColumnTypeOfReporter = 5
```

this also worked quite fine.
At the end I cancelled the cast, turned back to

```bsh
$ColumnInsight = 6
$ColumnHashtag = 7
$ColumnTypeOfReporter = 5
```

and ... now it worked. Why?

I even closed the PowerShell ISE and reopened it, reloaded the application, but now it continues to work fine. Same code as before.

Comment: If you `[string]$x = "test"` then `$x = 5` it will still by typed as a string. I guess you had done something to type `$ColumnRe` as a non-numeric type, and that was stuck in your running session, so even though you assign `5` to it, that value was being cast to another type and throwing an exception when passing it to Excel. But we can't see your ISE history, your code works, and the only thing we can do is guess - I think that makes it off-topic for StackOverflow as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced"

Comment: thx a lot, that was the reason.